# Mobile CSS rizing window instead of going past width

Tags: html, css

If I have something like this:

```
.div {
    width: 105vw;
}
```

It won't go past the browser window. Instead, it will just make the browser wider. Does the same thing when I use a media query with max-width of `475px` and I set the width to `600px`. How do I get it to go past the screen? I am trying to do this:

// Make the div go past the screen on both sides

```
.div {
    position: relative;
    width: 105vw;
    left: -8px;
}
```

And that seems to work on desktop, but not mobile.

Edit:
Viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: When you tried it, did you give the body a width of `100vh`?

Comment: @Santi I've tried with a width bigger than the media query in px, and i've tried 105vw.

Comment: Yes but if you do an `overflow: hidden;` without assigning a width, it won't do anything, because it will expand to fit it's content. By doing `body {width: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}` you're saying "the body should always be the width of the device, and should not add scrollbars to show anything in excess."

Comment: Ok, so my media query is 475px, ive set the size of my div to 1000px, i've gotten overflow:hidden and I still get the same result.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that no matter what size I set the width of the div, the browser just resizes to accommodate it, even if it goes past the media query. Doesnt matter if I used overflow or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do media queries have to do with it? A media query `max-width` applies conditional styles based on the width of the window, but it doesn't *set* a width, nor a max-width. It has no affect on the body at all. [See this example of what I'm talking about](https://jsfiddle.net/krLjv9fy/)

Comment: My media query is max-width: 475px, but my div is 1000px and all of it is displaying on the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125962/discussion-between-marc-hoover-and-santi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the iPhone browser is zooming out to fit the entire contents of the page by default. The solution is to replace the `<meta>` tag with one that sets the initial scale, like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```